# Sum values from numpy array if condition on value in another array is met

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm facing a problem with vectorizing a function so that it applies efficiently on a numpy array.

My program entries :

- A **pos_part** 2D Array of *Nb_particles* lines, 3 columns (basicaly x,y,z coordinates, only z is relevant for the part that bothers me) *Nb_particles* can up to several hundreds of thousands.
- An **prop_part** 1D array with *Nb_particles* values. This part I got covered, creation is made with some nice numpy functions ; I just put here a basic distribution that ressembles real values.
- A **z_distances** 1D Array, a simple np.arange betwwen z=0 and z=z_max.

Then come the calculation that takes time, because where I can't find a way to do things properply with only numpy operation of arrays. What i want to do is :

- For all distances *z_i* in **z_distances**, sum all values from **prop_part** if corresponding particle coordinate z_particle < z_i. This would return a 1D array the same length as **z_distances**.

My ideas so far :

- Version 0, *for* loop, *enumerate* and *np.where* do retrieve the index of values that I need to sum. Obviously quite long.
- Version 1, using a mask on a new array (combination of z coordinates and particle properties), and sum on the masked array. Seems better than v0
- Version 2, another mask and a *np.vectorize*, but i understand it's not efficient as vectorize is basicaly a *for* loop. Still seems better than v0
- Version 3, I'm trying to use mask on a function that can I directly apply to z_distances, but it's not working so far.

So, here I am. There is maybe something to do with a sort and a cumulative sum, but I don't know how to do this, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Please find below the code to make things clearer

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creation of particles' positions
Nb_part = 150_000
pos_part = 10*np.random.rand(Nb_part,3)
pos_part[:,0] = pos_part[:,1] = 0

#usefull property creation
beta = 1/1.5
prop_part = (1/beta)*np.exp(-pos_part[:,2]/beta)
z_distances = np.arange(0,10,0.1)


#my version 0
t0=time.time()
result = np.empty(len(z_distances))
for index_dist, val_dist in enumerate(z_distances):
    positions = np.where(pos_part[:,2]<val_dist)[0]
    result[index_dist] = sum(prop_part[i] for i in positions)
print("v0 :",time.time()-t0)

#A graph to help understand
plt.figure()
plt.plot(z_distances,result, c="red")
plt.ylabel("Sum of particles' usefull property for particles with z-pos<d")
plt.xlabel("d")


#version 1 ??
t1=time.time()
combi = np.column_stack((pos_part[:,2],prop_part))
result2 = np.empty(len(z_distances))
for index_dist, val_dist in enumerate(z_distances):
    mask = (combi[:,0]<val_dist)
    result2[index_dist]=sum(combi[:,1][mask])
print("v1 :",time.time()-t1)
plt.plot(z_distances,result2, c="blue")


#version 2
t2=time.time()
def themask(a):
    mask = (combi[:,0]<a)
    return sum(combi[:,1][mask])
thefunc = np.vectorize(themask)
result3 = thefunc(z_distances)
print("v2 :",time.time()-t2)
plt.plot(z_distances,result3, c="green")


### This does not work so far
# version 3
# =============================
# t3=time.time()
# def thesum(a):
#     mask = combi[combi[:,0]<a]
#     return sum(mask[:,1])
# result4 = thesum(z_distances)
# print("v3 :",time.time()-t3)
# =============================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a lot more performance by writing your first version completely in numpy. Replace pythons `sum` with `np.sum`. Instead of the `for i in positions` list comprehension, simply pass the `positions` mask you are creating anyways.
Indeed, the `np.where` is not necessary and my best version looks like:

```
#my version 0
t0=time.time()
result = np.empty(len(z_distances))
for index_dist, val_dist in enumerate(z_distances):
    positions = pos_part[:, 2] < val_dist
    result[index_dist] = np.sum(prop_part[positions])
print("v0 :",time.time()-t0)
# out: v0 : 0.06322097778320312
```

You can get a bit faster if z_distances is very long by using `numba`.
Running `calc` for the first time usually creates some overhead which we can get rid of by running the function for some small set of `z_distances.
The below code achieves roughly a factor of two speedup over pure numpy on my laptop.

```
import numba as nb
@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def calc(result, z_distances):
    n = z_distances.shape[0]
    for ii in nb.prange(n):
        pos = pos_part[:, 2] < z_distances[ii]
        result[ii] = np.sum(prop_part[pos])
    return result

result4 = np.zeros_like(result)
# _t = time.time()
# calc(result4, z_distances[:10])
# print(time.time()-_t)
t3 = time.time()
result4 = calc(result4, z_distances)
print("v3 :", time.time()-t3)
plt.plot(z_distances, result4)
```